# How to achieve mutual comparison between ABCDEFG?

Tags: r

For example, A & B, A & C...A & G? then, B & C, B & D...B & G? ...then, E & F, E & G, F & G? My code is as follows.

```
library(basicTrendline) 
x<-RL$A 
y<-RL$B
trendline(x,y,model="line3P",ePos.x = "topleft",
             linecolor = "black",CI.color = NA, eDigit=2, 
             xlab=c("Abiomass(g)"), ylab=c("Bbiomass(g)"), text.col="red")
```

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by mutual comparison? Can you share an example of `RL` (i.e. by adding the results of `dput(head(RL))` to your question)

Answer (score 1):

```
pairs(RL, panel = panel.smooth)
```

Comment: How do I add the fitting equation and R2 to pairs packages?